# image can not be seen in htdocs?

Tags: webserver, lamp, html

I am using Ubuntu 12.10 and recently have installed xampp 1.8.1. My problem is: image from server can not be shown.

my code is ::

```
<div class="sideBlock unSung">
    <h4>Unsung heroes...</h4>
    <a href="#"> <img src="_images/1_full.jpg" alt="Midnight Run" width="99" height="135" /> </a>

    <a href="#"><img src="_images/2d7y3ki.jpg" alt="Wyatt Earp" width="99" height="135" /></a>
</div>
```

here, in my address bar I use

```
 http://localhost/madeTemplet/basicTemplet/templet03.html
```

and I want to show image after "Unsung heroes" text but it only shown some link and not any image

But when I use the following

```
file:///opt/lampp/htdocs/madeTemplet/basicTemplet/templet03.html
```

and images are shown after **Unsung heroes** text.

It works well in windows platform.

After checking the permissions to access the directory where images are, I get this text in my terminal window ::

```
  sabbir@sabbir-pc:/opt/lampp/htdocs/madeTemplet/basicTemplet/_images$ ls -l
  total 300
 -rw------- 1 sabbir sabbir 204067 Feb 24  2010 1_full.jpg
 -rw------- 1 sabbir sabbir  75789 Nov 13  2009 2d7y3ki.jpg
 -rw------- 1 sabbir sabbir  23692 Apr 21  2010 6AB32AE44600435B9DE0FB5EBA24A912.gif
```

As a new user I can't insert image so you can check the given link as follow :

```
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16178342/image-can-not-be-seen-in-htdocs-in-ubuntu-12-10
```

Comment: Directory structure (`ls -l`, as Stef noted) of `htdocs` would be helpful. Also: Please do give screenshots rather than descriptions of visual phenomenons (in this case, the "some link and not ny image") Please edit any further info into your question itself.

Comment: I am using "ubuntu 12.10" and my browser is "mozilla firefox"

Comment: Could be the case of faulty permissions, that is Apache does not have enough permissions to access the directory where images are? You can check this and post the output using `ls -l` to see who owns the directory.

Comment: It shows look like the following ::
-rw------- 1 sabbir sabbir 204067 Feb 24 2010 1_full.jpg
here 'sabbir' is my computer name

Comment: For full image you can check this link :: "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16178342/image-can-not-be-seen-in-htdocs-in-ubuntu-12-10"

Answer (score 0):

Two things are comming to mind, the first is permissions and the second false path to image.

You could try **only for testing** purposes to:

- give ownership to Apache i.e: `chown -R www-data:www-data` where www-data the Apache user and group.
- use hardcoded path to image i.e: `<a href="#"> <img src="/opt/lampp/htdocs/madeTemplet/basicTemplet/_images/1_full.jpg"...`

Hopefully you will be able to find the problem.

**Rebember** to revert the changes after testing acoordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change permission of your htdocs folder

you can try this::

```
  1)  sudo -s

  2)  give your password

  3)  sudo chmod 777 -R /opt/lampp/htdocs
```

Answer (score 0):

DO NOT use the 'chown' or 'chmod' command lightly. I've done that and trust me it is not a piece of cake to revert to the initial configuration after that. So I've had this problem for a while now and I finally figured out a solution to it although it's only to be used as a last resort:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /opt/lampp/htdocs/path/to/image/folder
```

this basically gives you all permissions pertaining to all the images stored in that folder. Cheers!